# Adding 2 series with different type of data in legends in one Apexcharts

Tags: typescript, apexcharts

I'm trying to make some button with Daily and Weekly. When I click daily button it would be show up daily chart time and data, if I click weekly button it would be show up weekly chart time and data.

When I try to input daily and monthly it's fail to have two series like my code.

So how can I make this work properly with two series or some tweaks in API place?

```js
//Energy Daily
        this._lookupService.getEnergyGraphDaily(s).then(
            (energydaily) => {
                console.log("efg Daily", energydaily)
                this.energy = energydaily
                this._prepareEnergyDailyChartData(energydaily);
                this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )

        //Energy Weekly
        this._lookupService.getEnergyGraphWeekly(s).then(
            (energyweekly) => {
                console.log("efg Daily", energyweekly)
                this.energy = energyweekly
                this._prepareEnergyDailyChartData(energyweekly);
                this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    }
    
    private _prepareEnergyDailyChartData(energy: any, energyweekly: any): void {
        // data series and chart
        let energyChart: any = {
            series: {
                'daily': [
                    {
                        'name': 'Energy',
                        'data': energy.dataPLTS
                    },
                ],
                'monthly': [
                    {
                        'name': 'Energy',
                        'data': energyweekly.dataPLTS
                    },
                ]
            }
        }

        console.log("seriesEnergy", energyChart)

        // Energy
        this.chartEnergy = {
            chart: {
                animations: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                fontFamily: 'inherit',
                foreColor: 'inherit',
                height: '100%',
                type: 'area',
                toolbar: {
                    show: false
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            colors: ['#64748B', '#94A3B8'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            fill: {
                colors: ['#64748B', '#94A3B8'],
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            grid: {
                show: false,
                padding: {
                    bottom: -40,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            series: energyChart.series,
            stroke: {
                curve: 'smooth',
                width: 2
            },
            tooltip: {
                followCursor: true,
                theme: 'dark',
                x: {
                    format: 'MMM dd, yyyy'
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false
                },
                labels: {
                    offsetY: -20,
                    rotate: 0,
                    style: {
                        colors: 'var(--fuse-text-secondary)'
                    },
                    datetimeUTC: false
                },
                tickAmount: 3,
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        colors: 'var(--fuse-text-secondary)'
                    }
                },
                // max       : (max): number => max + 250,
                // min       : (min): number => min - 250,
                show: false,
                tickAmount: 5
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="ml-2">
                    <mat-button-toggle-group class="hidden sm:inline-flex border-none space-x-1" value="daily"
                        #energyTypeSelector="matButtonToggleGroup">
                        <mat-button-toggle class="px-1.5 rounded-full overflow-hidden border-none font-medium"
                            value="daily">Daily
                        </mat-button-toggle>
                        <mat-button-toggle class="px-1.5 rounded-full overflow-hidden border-none font-medium"
                            value="weekly">Weekly
                        </mat-button-toggle>
                    </mat-button-toggle-group>
                    <div class="sm:hidden">
                        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="energyMenu">
                            <mat-icon [svgIcon]="'heroicons_outline:dots-vertical'"></mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <mat-menu #energyMenu="matMenu">
                            <button mat-menu-item>Daily</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Weekly</button>
                        </mat-menu>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-start mt-6 mx-6">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-8 sm:gap-12">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="font-medium text-secondary leading-5">
                                Overall Daily Energy
                            </div>
                            <mat-icon class="ml-1.5 icon-size-4 text-hint"
                                [svgIcon]="'heroicons_solid:information-circle'" [matTooltip]="
                                    'Score is calculated by using the historical ratio between Page Views and Visitors. Best score is 1000, worst score is 0.'
                                "></mat-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-start mt-2">
                            <div class="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight leading-none">
                                <!-- {{ data.visitorsVsPageViews.overallScore }} -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center ml-2">
                                <mat-icon class="icon-size-5 text-green-500" [svgIcon]="
                                        'heroicons_solid:arrow-circle-up'
                                    "></mat-icon>
                                <div class="ml-1 text-md font-medium text-green-500">
                                    42.9%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="font-medium text-secondary leading-5">
                                Overall Monthly Energy
                            </div>
                            <mat-icon class="ml-1.5 icon-size-4 text-hint"
                                [svgIcon]="'heroicons_solid:information-circle'" [matTooltip]="
                                    'Average Ratio is the average ratio between Page Views and Visitors'
                                "></mat-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-start mt-2">
                            <div class="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight leading-none">
                                <!-- {{
                                data.visitorsVsPageViews.averageRatio
                                | number : "1.0-0"
                                }}% -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center ml-2">
                                <mat-icon class="icon-size-5 text-red-500" [svgIcon]="
                                        'heroicons_solid:arrow-circle-down'
                                    "></mat-icon>
                                <div class="ml-1 text-md font-medium text-red-500">
                                    13.1%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="font-medium text-secondary leading-5">
                                Overall Yearly Energy
                            </div>
                            <mat-icon class="ml-1.5 icon-size-4 text-hint"
                                [svgIcon]="'heroicons_solid:information-circle'" [matTooltip]="
                                    'Predicted Ratio is calculated by using historical ratio, current trends and your goal targets.'
                                "></mat-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-start mt-2">
                            <div class="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight leading-none">
                                <!-- {{
                                data.visitorsVsPageViews.predictedRatio
                                | number : "1.0-0"
                                }}% -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center ml-2">
                                <mat-icon class="icon-size-5 text-green-500" [svgIcon]="
                                        'heroicons_solid:arrow-circle-up'
                                    "></mat-icon>
                                <div class="ml-1 text-md font-medium text-green-500">
                                    22.2%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Chart Energy -->
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto h-80 mt-3">
                <apx-chart *ngIf="[energyTypeSelector].value === daily" class="flex-auto w-full h-full" [chart]="chartEnergy.chart" [colors]="chartEnergy.colors"
                    [dataLabels]="chartEnergy.dataLabels" [grid]="chartEnergy.grid" [legend]="chartEnergy.legend"
                    [series]="chartEnergy.series[energyTypeSelector.value]" [stroke]="chartEnergy.stroke"
                    [tooltip]="chartEnergy.tooltip" [xaxis]="chartEnergy.xaxis" [yaxis]="chartEnergy.yaxis"></apx-chart>
                    
                    <apx-chart *ngIf="[energyTypeSelector].value === weekly" class="flex-auto w-full h-full" [chart]="chartEnergy.chart" [colors]="chartEnergy.colors"
                    [dataLabels]="chartEnergy.dataLabels" [grid]="chartEnergy.grid" [legend]="chartEnergy.legend"
                    [series]="chartEnergy.series[energyTypeSelector.value]" [stroke]="chartEnergy.stroke"
                    [tooltip]="chartEnergy.tooltip" [xaxis]="chartEnergy.xaxis" [yaxis]="chartEnergy.yaxis"></apx-chart>
            </div>
```